# Button Functions running until mouse unclicked

Tags: python-3.x, button, pygame

I've made a few buttons, although when I click down on the buttons to run the function, the button runs repeatedly until I release the click. Is there a way to get the function to run once per click down rather then until it is released. Here it the button function:

```
def Button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, lightgrey, (x, y, w, h))
            if action == "undo":
                print("hey")
```

Printing hey is to test when undo is clicked. But depending on how slightly the button is pressed it prints at least hey 5 times as I cannot release the click down fast enough.

Comment: I think you want to use the event type `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` here

Comment: Also, instead of passing in a string like `"undo"` you should pass in the `undo`-function and call it if supplied

Comment: are you able to give me an example, kind seem to find the information I need to implement using that event type.
I understand what you're saying just unsure where to place it within the code

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have pygame on my current machine and it would be very adventurous to dump code without testing. But - lucky you - there are plenty examples in the pygame docs [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)

Comment: you are a real hero, thankyou <3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can re-create the function like this:

```
def button(x, y, w, h, inactive, active, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        gameDisplay.blit(active, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
            action()
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(inactive, (x, y))
```

After you have done that, you can call it like this:

```
#For Example
button(100, 350, 195, 80, startBtn, startBtn_hover, game_loop)
```

Here is what each parameter means:

- x: x-coordinate of button
- y: y-coordinate of button
- w: width of button
- h: height of button
- active: picture of button when the mouse is hovering over it
- inactive: picture of button when it is idle
- action: the function executed when the button is clicked